# Magento 2 The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again

Tags: inventory, cataloginventory

**This is the log i found. i don't know why its happening when creating a new product.**

[2022-09-27 07:10:49] main.CRITICAL: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. at /home//public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:187, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`<hide>_magento3`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `<hide>_magento`.`catalog_product_e...), query was:

INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `min_sale_qty`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`, `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at

/home//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`<hide>_magento3`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `<hide>_magento`.`catalog_product_e...) at /home//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []

Also some inventory related modules are disabled here is the list.

```
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryRequisitionList
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
```